# C++ hdr image i/o library (linux and windows)

Tags: c++, linux, image, io

I need to find/create a library that can load hdr images in many formats for use in opengl.

I have been using SDL_image, but it doesn't support hdr.

I don't want to use many different image libraries, so if there is one that supports a large amount (bmp, png, jpg, tiff, tga, hdr are the most important).

If there is none, I don't mind writing my own, but I need a good specification.  There doesn't seem to be all that much information that I can find via google though, so I need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)? You can install [HDRI](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php) support, apparently. Looks like it can be used with [openGL](http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-developers/2005-July/002276.html), though I'm not sure if that suits your needs.

Comment: Excellent, easy to use library. I changed all my code in a matter of minutes, and am now adding hdr support :).